# only first value is changed when iterating through express-handlebars each

Tags: javascript, express-handlebars

I am using express-handlebars in my node application. In one of my forms I am storing data in the format 2018-12-01 (YYYY MM DD) as a string. I am also storing time as string in 24 hour format 13:45:00

I have defined a script to use moment for changing the date format:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var NowMoment = $('#displayMoment').val();
        var Date = moment(NowMoment);
        var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementById('output');
        // display output in the preferred format
        eDisplayMoment.innerHTML = Date.format('MMM Do YYYY');
    })();
</script>
```

in my .handlebars template I am displaying the data received using the following code:

```
{{#each tasks}}
    <input id="displayMoment" value="{{taskDate}}" hidden>
    <p>{{taskName}} {{taskDate}} {{taskTime}} {{taskStatus}} <span id="output"></span>


        <a class="btn u-btn-primary g-rounded-50 g-py-5" href="/starttask/{{id}}">
            <i class="fa fa-edit g-mr-5"></i> start task
        </a>
    </p>
    {{/each}}
```

as you can see I have a hidden input which is assigned the {{taskDate}}, I fetch its value in the script and format it to display in the span tag.

**The Problem is:**
Only the first task is formatting the date and showing it, the second or consecutive tasks do not show the formatted date.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your issue, not sure what the problem is. By second or consecutive tasks do you mean other html elements using the {{taskDate}} value aren't properly formatted?

Comment: I am using a {{#each}} {{/each}} loop to display all the tasks. Each task has the {{startDate}} which needs to be formatted and displayed in the proper format. The issue is that only the startDate for the first task is shown formatted, but second, third and so on are now shown at all.

Comment: Is your <script> tag at the bottom of your page or top?

Comment: It was at the bottom of the page, I have also tried moving it within the {{#each}} but same result

Comment: ok no worries, give my answer a try and see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **id cannot be the same**. The HTML specification requires it to be **unique**. So can lets remove the id attribute from your `span` and `input` elements and instead give them an appropriate `class` attribute definition instead:

```
<span class="output"></span>

<input class="displayMoment" value="{{taskDate}}" hidden>
```

Then lets use `getElementsByClassName(...)` instead of `document.getElementById(...)` since according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), `getElementById()` returns a **single** element object representing the element whose id property matches the specified string. Assuming a 1 to 1 relationship between input values and the spans we are trying to change the value for we can do something along the lines of this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            var inputEles = document.getElementsByClassName("displayMoment");
            var spanEles = document.getElementsByClassName("output");
            for(var i=0; i<spanEles.length; i++) {
              var Date = moment(inputEles[i].value);
              spanEles[i].innerHTML = Date.format('MMM Do YYYY');
            }
        })();
    </script>
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: made the changes. For some reason it is now showing me the same date for both tasks

Comment: that is because it get this value: $('#displayMoment').val() and set the spans accordingly. Lets do the same thing with the input element and it should work fine

Comment: A bit confused...I have changed the input tag by changing the id to class but there is no change in terms of the date.shows the same date for both the tasks

Comment: Give me a min and I will adjust my answer to help.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, much appreciate it

Comment: Np, give the latest answer a try and we will keep tweaking until we get it to do exactly what you want it to :)

Comment: Just tried it...but now the dates are not showing at all

Comment: I goofed on a variable name, try it now

Comment: I just tried console.loging them...in my browser console I am getting the error elementsis not defined.

Comment: Yes retry my code, I forgot I renamed elements to spanEles I changed the answer to reflect this already

Comment: Bingo....that's it...working fine now. Thanks Nathan, much appreciate it. You were very patient.

Comment: np glad I was able to help! Please upvote and accept my answer :) sorry I made careless mistake